# How can I modify all indices after a given index in a 2D tensor?

Tags: pytorch

Given a 2D tensor and a 1D tensor of indices, I'm looking for a way to modify the values of each of the 2D tensor's row w.r.t to the 1D tensor:

```
>>> A = torch.randn(5,5)
>>> A
tensor([[ 0.0265,  0.1408,  1.6343,  0.3062,  0.3950],
        [ 0.6614,  1.6490, -1.8821, -0.2621,  1.4919],
        [ 1.0964,  1.5243,  0.5565, -0.7764, -1.2834],
        [-1.2818, -0.9590, -0.8375, -1.3218,  0.1081],
        [ 1.4578,  0.6749, -1.7441,  0.6515,  0.7278]])
>>> idx = torch.randint(0, A.shape[0], (5, ))
>>> idx
tensor([0, 1, 2, 1, 3])
>>> B = do_something(A, idx, 0)
>>> B
tensor([[ 0.0265,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.6614,  1.6490, 0., 0.,  0.],
        [ 1.0964,  1.5243,  0.5565, 0., 0.],
        [-1.2818, -0.9590, 0., 0.,  0.],
        [ 1.4578,  0.6749, -1.7441,  0.6515,  0.]])
```

I know this can probably be done with a for loop, but I wanted to know if there's any way to do this with only pytorch functions.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, if idx[0]==i, the elements starting from row 0, column i+1 in A will be set to 0. You can use `expand` in torch to operate. code show as below:

```py
A = torch.randn(5, 5)
idx = torch.randint(0, A.shape[0], (5, ))
print(A)
print(idx)
idx = idx.unsqueeze(1).expand(5, 5)
B = torch.zeros_like(A)
mask = torch.arange(5, device=A.device) <= idx
B[mask] = A[mask]
print(B)
```

In this code, first expand idx to a 5*5 matrix B with all elements of row i in B as idx[i]. Next, we look for positions in A that do not need to be set to 0, i.e., positions in row i that are <= i. Finally, we initialize a 0 matrix and assign the positions that do not need to be set to 0 to the corresponding values in A.